# Movie about space rangers fighting giant yellow bugs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think it’s a 90’s scifi movie about giant alien bugs attacking a space ship with lots of people on it and there are a couple of rangers fighting them. If I recall correctly they kinda look like giant yellow wasps with venoms that can melt metal just like in aliens. I think the name of the movie is something like Space Rangers (not the space rangers TV series) but I’m not sure. I watched it in the 90s when I was a kid and the memories keep on coming back now and I’m curious about it but I can’t find anything about it on the internet.

Comment: Starship Troopers?

Comment: Live-action movie or animated?

Comment: Has the spaceship landed or put the people on a planet where they're fighting bugs, or are the bugs actually in space fighting?

Comment: Its a live action movie not animated. It’s all in space aboard a spaceship.

Comment: Just spitballing here, but there's a couple of scenes in the "Lost in space" movie with Mat LeBlanc where they're fighting space spider things, could it be that?

Comment: No it’s not lost in space.

Answer (score 2):

Starship Troppers 1997
If it's not this one it might be one of the sequels

Comment: "*all in space aboard a spaceship.*" doesn't sound like Starship Troopers.

Comment: Nope not starship troopers.

Comment: Maybe this one Space Raider.  It seems to have different types of aliens and it is in space https://youtu.be/XBham6MnKYE

Comment: I stumbled across this on the amazon website but can't seem to find any more info on it. I know there is a TV movie from 2015 called Space Ranger but am not sure if this is the same thing, if so its too recent for this question... https://www.amazon.com/Space-Ranger/dp/B00WRVMN1O

Comment: skyjack   The Space Ranger film from the amazon link is called "Galaxy Hunter" and it's from 2004.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the film "[Dead Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Space_(film))" (1991)

A Roger Corman production, a remake in fact of an earlier Roger Corman production "Forbidden World" (1982) [aka "Subject 20" aka "The Mutant"]

> In the research facility on the planet Phablos, a virus is created in a botched experiment which turns those infected into monsters. An emergency distress call is sent from the lab. A spacecraft crewed by Commander Steve Krieger and robot sidekick Tinpan respond to the emergency call from the planet, but their craft is attacked and damaged on the way to Phablos.
>
> Upon their arrival at Phablos, those in charge of the laboratory explain that they have managed to contain the virus. Krieger accepts the lab's claims and begins repairs on his ship. The scientist had not been entirely honest with Krieger, and had been attempting to study the virus rather than contain it.
>
> Unfortunately, the virus escapes and infects a lab worker, leaving the lab to face a killer virus that turns them into alien monsters.
>
> Krieger and Tinpan attempt to stop the monster, but their weapons prove ineffective. One of the lab workers develops a bioweapon that proves effective in stopping the monster.

### "Dead Space" Trailer

Comment: Wow, look how young [Malcolm's dad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Cranston) is in this one, must be a few years before he had kids, or Malcolm *et al* really took it out of him. :)